# How can I connect a thin relay to a 220V wire?

Tags: wiring

Im almost an absolute beginner in the electrical field. I have bought a relay and wires (for a 60W light), however once unpacked I see that the relay is very thin.

I have tried to use a crocodile clamp but it seems too big. I have a breadboard but Im afraid the current will be too much (it is a 60W light, not an LED)

I think that soldering them together will be too weak. Any idea ?

EDIT : 220VAV / 2A for the relay, this is for a small light (220V / 60W)

[image]

Comment: Can you say what the voltage and current ratings for the relay contacts are, please?

Comment: Looks like the relay says "2A 250VAC"

Comment: You need a 5A relay to switch that load - turn-on current for a 60W light bulb is 15x higher than when it has warmed up, so you are switching just over 4A for a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relay is designed to be soldered to a PCB. You can solder wires directly to it, but it will not be  a strong connection. You could try soldering it to a scrap of Veroboard (stripboard) and then connecting the wires to the board.

Probably best not to use those uninsulated crocodile clips (or are they alligator clips?) with 220V.

The best way is to get a bigger relay with bigger terminals. It's possible to buy relays which plug in to a base or socket. The base then has screw terminals for the wires.

Do not use a solderless breadboard for making 220V AC connections like this.

Comment: follow up question : I have bought a stripboard and soldered the relay to it, but the wires are too big to fit in the holes. I am supposed to gently drill holes ?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, you can carefully drill the holes out a little. Stripboard holes are usually 1mm diameter, so a 1.5mm drill would be OK. Or, you can connect the wire flat against the back of the stripboard, along the track. Be sure not to make any shorts!